# change firefox profile in selenium

Tags: perl, selenium

I am trying to change the firefox profile used by selenium in order to allow file downloads without having to confirm.
I have tried by creating a profile:
1) I ran firefox -p
2) clicked "create_profile" and gave it a name
3) I chnaged some settings in it and closed firefox.

I am running selenium-standalone server 3.5.
From what I understand I should be able to change the profile loaded when running firefox using **-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile** so having named the profile selenium I started selenium like this:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=<path_to_geckdriver> -
 Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=selenium -jar <selenium_jar>
```

This starts selenium properly and I am able to create firefox sessions.
However, Selenium loads the default profile and puts it in Temp.

I also did this, in order to create a profile in perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Firefox;
my  $profile = Selenium::Firefox::Profile->new();    $profile-set_preference("browser.download.dir" => "C:\\Downloads");
profile>set_boolean_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting"=> 0);    
$profile>set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/octet-stream");
$profile->set_preference("browser.download.folderList"=> 2);
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new('firefox_profile' => $profile); 
$driver->get('http://www.colorado.edu/conflict/peace/download/peace.zip');
print $driver->get_title();
$driver->quit();
```

However selenium appears to still use default setup.
I am still prompted when it wants to download.
What is the name of the property which sets selenium's default firefox profile?
Do I need to specify profile directory as well?
If so, how do I do this?

I hope that I have given enough information and that my question is clear enough.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The profile is actually sent by the client side and not on server side. So I don't think this would work. You need to send the profile from where you are initiating the driver

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
So this means my second aproach should work?
Although I haven't got it to work.

Comment: See if this helps https://rdrr.io/cran/RSelenium/man/makeFirefoxProfile.html

Comment: Well I would rather not involve yet another programing language :)

Comment: My bad i just looked at the syntax and assumed R instead of perl. Should have looked at the tag correctly

Comment: Can you open `about:config` in the firefox opened and see if the changes you made are there or not? So we know what part is working and what is not

Comment: The changes are not there, then again I am not sure if I am using the proper keysin set_preference(...)